# boost graph metric_tsp_approx solution not following graph edges

Tags: c++, boost, traveling-salesman, boost-graph

I am trying to solve the traveling salesmen problem on a graph created using boost::adjacency_list. I am using the [metric_tsp_approx](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/graph/doc/metric_tsp_approx.html) to solve the tsp.
The problem I am facing is that the solution does not follow the graph edges. The solution connects vertices in the graph which are not directly connected. I wanted to know if this is how the library works or if I am doing something wrong. The solution does not look correct either. I had 4 vertices forming a square, the solution should have been going along the perimeter, but it was going along the diagonal instead. There was no edge along the diagonal.

This is my adjacency_list:

```cpp
boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS,
                                boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int>,
                                boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>,
                                boost::no_property>
```

Add vertex and add edge functions:

```cpp
boost::add_vertex(id, graph);
boost::add_edge(id1, id2, weight, graph);  // weight is euclidean distance
```

TSP solver:

```
std::vector<VertexDescriptor> tsp_path;  //VertexDescriptor is adjacency_list::vertex_descriptor
metric_tsp_approx_tour(graph, back_inserter(tsp_path));
```

I also tried passing the weightmap to the `metric_tsp_approx_tour` but the same problem persists.

Can someone help me solve this? If the boost metric_tsp_approx_tour does not consider the edges of the graph, is there a way to make it consider them?

Answer (score 1):

The docs: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/graph/doc/metric_tsp_approx.html

> This is a traveling salesperson heuristic for generating a tour of vertices for a **fully connected** undirected graph with weighted edges that obey the triangle inequality.

*(emphasis mine)*

The ["fully connected graph"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FullyConnectedGraph.html) clause does state that all vertices are assumed to be connected.

Note as well, the vertex index is assumed to map to [0,num_vertices(graph)).

### BONUS

As a bonus I tried to work out a minimal working example for the algorithm. It does seem to work as advertised:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/086a1e830203d21f)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/metric_tsp_approx.hpp>

using Graph = 
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS,
        boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int>,
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>,
        boost::no_property>;

using VertexDescriptor = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

int main() {
    std::vector const points { std::pair
        { 4., 9. }, // these can be randomized
        { 2., 6. },
        { 4., 1. },
        { 1., 1. },
    };

    Graph graph;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < points.size(); ++i) {
        add_vertex(i, graph);
    }

    for (auto i = 0u; i < points.size(); ++i) {
        auto va = vertex(i, graph);

        // undirected, so only need traverse higher vertices for connections
        for (auto j = i+1; j < points.size(); ++j) {
            auto vb = vertex(j, graph);

            auto const [ax, ay] = points.at(i);
            auto const [bx, by] = points.at(j);
            auto const dx = bx - ax;
            auto const dy = by - ay;

            add_edge(va, vb, sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy), graph); // weight is euclidean distance
        }
    }

    print_graph(graph);

    std::vector<VertexDescriptor> tsp_path(num_vertices(graph));  //VertexDescriptor is adjacency_list::vertex_descriptor
    metric_tsp_approx_tour(graph, back_inserter(tsp_path));

    auto idmap = get(boost::vertex_index, graph);
    for (auto vd : tsp_path) {
        if (vd != graph.null_vertex()) {
            auto [x,y] = points.at(idmap[vd]); 
            std::cout << " {" << x << "," << y << "}";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
0 <--> 1 2 3 
1 <--> 0 2 3 
2 <--> 0 1 3 
3 <--> 0 1 2 
 {4,9} {2,6} {1,1} {4,1} {4,9}
```

Comment: Added a [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/086a1e830203d21f)